# Changing age verification box placement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, splash-screen

Currently I have a Age Verification Splash page on which I am a bit lost.

I have a working script that redirects to google if under 18, and sends you to main site if 18 or older.

I have not dealt with splash pages so this is new to me. Does it reference my css file? Do I add any css stuff right there? Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Website is Vaporwrx.com (Currently its all white and the 'box' is in the top left. I need to move the box to the center and change the background color or add an image. Here is the code I am working with

```
    <head>

    <script language="javascript">
    function checkAge()
    {
    /* the minumum age you want to allow in */
    var min_age = 18;

    /* change "age_form" to whatever your form has for a name="..." */
    var year = parseInt(document.forms["age_form"]["year"].value);
    var month = parseInt(document.forms["age_form"]["month"].value) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(document.forms["age_form"]["day"].value);

    var theirDate = new Date((year + min_age), month, day);
    var today = new Date;

    if ( (today.getTime() - theirDate.getTime()) < 0) {


    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"

    return false;
    }
    else {
    /* set the age check cookie here so it can be found on all pages (if they have  cookies         enabled!) */
    return true;
    }
    }
    </script>

    **** PLEASE ENTER YOUR BIRTHDAY ****

    <form action="http://www.vaporwrx.com/default.asp" method="post" name="age_form">
    Day : <select name="day">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    </select>

    Month : <select name="month">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    </select>

    Year : <select name="year">
    <option>2013</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="senddate" value="Go" onClick="return checkAge()"> 
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before you form

`<link rel=StyleSheet href="../css/reports.css" type="text/css" media=screen>`

Wrap your form in a div...

```
<div id="age_form">  <!--form stuff --> </div>
```

Then in the CSS file:

```
#age_form
{
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    background-color:#00ff00;
}
```

Comment: Excuse my naiveness, I am still learning, quickly though! I am using a template based website (Volusion, what my boss purchased). By adding the div id into my code, it will reference my css as age_form?

Comment: So in my main website code, it uses 

 

        <link href="/v/vspfiles/templates/VaporWorks/css/Imports.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



Should I use that as my link since its referencing my css page via web host?

Comment: You can add the css to that css file if you have access to it.  Otherwise its okay to have more than one css file.

Comment: Yes I have access to it. And seeing as how new I am I think I'll stick with one clean page :)  

Thanks so much for your help! You're awesome! +1 for you!